# Как на js изменить текст поля на другом сайте?

Tags: javascript

Кто-то заходит на сайт example.com (сайт не принадлежит автору js кода). На нём есть поле с id="id". Какой js код может (юзер вставит его в консоль браузера) изменить текст поля?

Answer (score 1):

Можно найти элемент по id и изменить атрибут value элемента input

```
input = document.getElementById("input-id")
input.value = 'Текст в input'
```